# Create Dummy CPU Performance counter register for Unit Testing of Driver

Tags: unit-testing, x86-64, cpu, device-driver, performancecounter

I want to test device driver which fetches the CPU performance counter values from the CPU registers.

1. Is there any way where the driver could read dummy data from memory/file instead of CPU registers ?
2. Is there any way where I could write a value directly in CPU perf counter registers and read it back after executing asm code snippet.

Comment: 1. Yes, of course. This can range from a compile-time configuration (e.g. `#ifdef`) to proper unit testing. 2. It depends on the architecture. For x86, the counters are writable IIRC. This question needs more focus, though. You need to add an architecture tag and do some research.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
For (2), Lets say for AMD x64 architecture, I would like to program the performance counter registers to reset it to 0 and then execute some assembly instructions and have the counters incremented, and then read back the counter values.